# Combo Box Objects List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a form where one field should be a collection of objects (0 or more) from another table using combox/multiple-select dropdown, what is the best practice to establish this? e.g:

```
public class Person{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string PersonName  { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    ///or
    public IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    ///or
    public IEnumerable<Addresses > Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to populate your address list in your controller and use the Html.DropDownList helper to create your drop down.

For example:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var addressList = <YourAddressListHere>;
   ViewData["Addresses"] = new SelectList(addressList, "<ValueProperty>", "<NameProperty>");
   return View();
}
```

And in your view (Razor syntax):

```
@Html.DropDownList("AddressDropDown", (ViewData["Addresses"] as SelectList))
```

There is also Html.ListBoxFor and Html.ListBox helpers if you wanted to do multi-select.  The same basic approach applies.

---

(EDIT)
Sorry for my misunderstanding.

To get the list of addresses that were selected you can add the control name as a parameter in you "POST" handler and extract them during the save/edit/insert function.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int[] addressList, <your parameters>)
.....
```

with the UI code as:

```
<div class="editor-field">    
    @Html.ListBox("addressList") 
</div>
```

You can do whatever you need with the list of address ID's that were selected.  I know that there is more than likely a better way to do this with MVC.  If anyone looks at this and knows a better way, please comment because I'd like to know myself.  I know that you can create some custom binder classes that I think will do all of this stuff automatically, but I haven't gotten that far yet with MVC.  I, myself, am a beginner with MVC.

In any case, I hope this helps a bit.

---

Comment: thanks for the reply. the problem is not the dropdown, i was able to establish that. im trying to store a "List<Addresses>" in the database, is that doable in C# MVC3?

Comment: I've edited the "answer" based on my misunderstanding of the question.  Hope this helps.